# Sum hours value, count and display based on hours using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which are Teacher and Activities.

```
CREATE TABLE teacher (
TeacherId INT, BranchId VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO teacher VALUES
("1121","A"),
("1132","A"),
("1141","A"),
("2120","B"), 
("2122","B");
                               
CREATE TABLE activities (
ID INT, TeacherID INT,    Hours   INT);

INSERT INTO activities VALUES
(1,1121,2),
(2,1121,1),
(3,1132,1),
(4,1141,NULL),
(5,2120,NULL),
(6,2122,NULL);
```

NULL indicates no activities and will be convert to 0 on output table. I want to produce a query to count total of hours and count how many activities base on teacher hours such as the following table:

```
   +-----------+------------+------------+
   |   Hours   |     A      |     B      |
   +-----------+------------+------------+
   |     0     |     1      |     2      |
   |     1     |     1      |     0      |
   |     2     |     0      |     0      |
   |     3     |     1      |     0      |
   +-----------+------------+------------+
```

Edited: Sorry I don't know how to elaborate accurately, but here is the fiddle i received from other member https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmtuZquKyUqdhPvTFN9qaF/1

Edit: Last, modification need, to sum the hours and count the hours base on branch id and teacher id as the output.

Expected output here (red text): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wyZ_aX5hz_7I1Ncf5sXLpstYk6FT8PMg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Null indicates that the number of activities is unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can handle this via the use of a calendar table of hours joined to an aggregation subquery:

```
SELECT
    t1.Hours,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BranchId = 'A' THEN t2.cnt ELSE 0 END) AS A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BranchId = 'B' THEN t2.cnt ELSE 0 END) AS B
FROM (SELECT 0 AS Hours UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t.BranchId, COALESCE(a.Hours, 0) AS Hours, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Teacher t
    LEFT JOIN Activities a ON a.TeacherId = t.TeacherId
    GROUP BY t.BranchId, COALESCE(a.Hours, 0)
) t2
    ON t1.Hours = t2.Hours
GROUP BY
    t1.Hours
ORDER BY
    t1.Hours
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it does not solve one more issue which is to count the hours base on teacher activities. Base on the data, it suppose to sum up the total hours for teacher if they have the same id. For example based on the data, row 3 hours should have 1 count for A because teacher ID 1121 made 2 activities, 1 and 2 hours.

Comment: See Gordon's reply to your comments.  You should accept an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a `JOIN` and aggregation . . . but you need to start with all the hours you want:

```
SELECT h.Hours,
       COALESCE(SUM(t.BranchId = 'A'), 0) AS A,
       COALESCE(SUM(t.BranchId = 'B'), 0) AS B
FROM (SELECT 0 AS Hours UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
     ) h LEFT JOIN
     activities a
     ON h.hours = COALESCE(a.hours, 0) LEFT JOIN
     teacher t
     ON t.TeacherId = a.TeacherId
GROUP BY h.Hours
ORDER BY h.Hours;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=76ec0f9d02d9dae3080f8c7ffb2179bb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it does not solve one more issue which is to count the hours base on teacher activities. Base on the data, it suppose to sum up the total hours for teacher if they have the same id. For example based on the data, row 3 hours should have 1 count for A because teacher ID 1121 made 2 activities, 1 and 2 hours.

Comment: @HanisHarun . . . This answers the question that is asked here and provides a db<>fiddle that illustrates that the solution produces *exactly* what you ask for.  If you have a *different* question it should be asked as a *new* question with appropriate explanation, sample data, and desired results.  And you should accept one of the answers to this question.

Comment: The answer does not solve the problem to sum and count the hours base on teacher id and group by branch. I update the fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mmtuZquKyUqdhPvTFN9qaF/1 and expected output here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wyZ_aX5hz_7I1Ncf5sXLpstYk6FT8PMg/view?usp=sharing